# import module in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have project dir as shown below

```
Project 
   cfg
        config.py
       __init__.py
   lib 
       script.py
       __init__.py
```

in script.py , I import config.py as

```
sc.addFile("<Project root>/cfg/config.py")
import config
```

Here  is hard-coded path,  I want to avoid this hard coding. what is best way to do it?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of `lib` so it's whether its under or next to `cfg`?

Comment: I have trouble believing that your import works. Could you show the error you get?

Comment: Both cfg and lib are under Project .

Comment: There is an "edit" button under your question that will allow you to fix that.

Comment: Does `Project` have and `__init__` file?

Comment: Also, what is `sc`?

Comment: No . Project has no init file and   sc is spark context

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way to do this would probably be to add `__init__.py` to `Project`, and then use a relative import:

```
from ..cfg import config
```